# How can I add information to custom user field (Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I create a custom field in user (using a Devise) in my Rails project, varible called information. Type is string.
Somethigh like that: `current_user.information`
How can I add another string to end of this string? 
I need a method then do like this:

```
current_user.information << some_varible
```

And save changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of `current_user.information` is a string you can append to it like you stated.

```
s = current_user.information
s << "New string addition"
s.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Except the `<<` method mentioned on @Rockwell's answer, you can achieve your goal by using `String#concat` as well:

```
s = current_user.information
s.concat("New string addition")
s.save
```